# A possible mistake in Walter Rudin, "Fourier analysis on groups"

Tags: harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, abelian-groups, pontrjagin-duality

I have the following lemma 4.2.4 on page 80 in the book (we have locally compact abelian topological groups $G_1, G_2$ and their duals $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$):

> Suppose $E$ is a coset in $\Gamma_2$ and $\alpha$ is an affine map of $E$ into $\Gamma_1$. THen $\alpha$ can be extended to an affine map of the closure $\overline{E}$ of $E$, and $\alpha(\overline{E})$ is a closed coset in $\Gamma_1$

I think $\alpha(\overline{E})$ is not necessary a closed coset in $\Gamma_1$. The book just states that it is a corollary of the uniform continuity of $\alpha$ but consider $E = \Gamma_2 = \mathbb{Q}$ with discrete topology, $\Gamma_1 = \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha$ is identity map. In that case, $\overline{E} = E$ and the image is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Edit: Since nobody proved the statement or pointed out where my example is wrong I'm going to assume the lemma is indeed incorrect.

Comment: What locally compact group $G_2$ has its dual group isomorphic to $\Gamma_2 = \mathbb{Q}$ with the discrete topology?

Comment: @NateEldredge $G_2$ is the dual of $\Gamma_2$, by the Pontrjagin duality.

Comment: @NateEldredge Is this question rhetorical? Every discrete abelian group has a compact Pontrjagin dual. Without thinking much, I imagine that the dual of ${\mathbb Q}_d$ has some kind of solenoidal flavour (it certainly isn't anything like compact Lie, of course)

Comment: @YemonChoi: No, it wasn't rhetorical, just naive :-)

Comment: The dual of $\mathbb Q$ is indeed a solenoid. You might call it "the" solenoid because it is the biggest, but that name is usually taken by the dual of $\mathbb Z[\frac12]$. Another name for the dual of $\mathbb Q$ is the adele quotient: $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$. Similarly, the binary solenoid is $(\mathbb R\times \mathbb Q_2)/\mathbb Z[\frac12]$.

Comment: Some written-out notes about various solenoids and their relation to number theory are easily "discoverable" on http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/ by searching for "solenoid" on that page.

Comment: @YemonChoi the dual of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is (non-canonically) isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}_p$ as a topological group. That it is totally disconnected is obvious (so, not really a solenoid), because duality exchanges totally disconnected groups and elliptic groups (elliptic means that every compact subset is contained in a compact subgroup).

Comment: Yes, it seems there's a mistake, if I understand the notation correctly. You even have a simpler counterexample by picking $G_1=\mathbf{Z}$ (discrete cyclic) $G_2=\mathbf{S}^1$ (the circle group); choose $E=\Gamma_2\simeq\mathbf{Z}$ and a dense embedding of $E$ into the circle group $\Gamma_1\simeq\mathbf{S}^1$. Indeed the last sentence evoking the uniform continuity (which was previously duly used to justify that $\alpha$ can be extended to the closure) seems incorrect.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the details. BTW I meant ${\bf Q}_d$ as the rationals with the discrete topology, not the $d$-adic integers.

Comment: I think the discussions above demonstrate that the OP is correct, and that this part of the lemma is incorrect. It seems, from my Canadian sources, that this error has been noticed tacitly by other people: see the remarks before and after Lemma 1.3 in: M. Ilie, N. Spronk, _Completely bounded homomorphisms of the Fourier algebras_, JFA 2005: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2004.11.011

Comment: @YemonChoi: ah OK (I'm used to consider the discrete topology as the natural topology on $\mathbf{Q}$ rather than any other and never saw this notation, but I understand).

Comment: @YCor, it's amazing what different things seem 'natural' depending on background.  (I was once deeply surprised to hear someone refer to the integers as unbounded, having forgotten that I was in a talk about real rather than $p$-adic groups.)  How do you refer to the rationals in the subspace topology from the reals (or from a $p$-adic field)?

Comment: @LSpice yes I'm aware of these topologies (that's why I said "rather than any other") but since none (in my opinion) is better than the other, without any reference I think of the discrete topology (and usually when we consider one of these [real or $p$-adic] topologies, the completion is more interesting).

Comment: @YCor, indeed, I didn't mean to suggest that you weren't aware of these topologies, just that I thought it was funny (in the sense merely of 'unusual', rather than 'wrong') not to regard one of them as natural.

Comment: @LSpice I said "*the* natural topology". I meant, the topology which should be implicit when no topology is specified, not that the various $p$-adic or the real topology are not natural. Similarly, I'd say that *the* natural topology on $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is the discrete topology, although it admits plenty of other interesting (and natural!) topologies.

Answer (score 6):

[This is just moving my comment to an answer so that the question does not keep showing up as unanswered.]

The discussions above seem to demonstrate that the OP is correct, and that this part of the lemma is incorrect. According to my Canadian sources, it seems that this error has been noticed tacitly by other people: see the remarks before and after Lemma 1.3 in:

> M. Ilie, N. Spronk. *Completely bounded homomorphisms of the Fourier algebras*, [J. Funct. Anal. **225** (2005) no. 2, 480–499](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2004.11.011)