# Empty interior of union of cosets?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

The following question arises from trying to understand Lemma 1.3(ii) of [arXiv:math/0405063](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405063.pdf).  I believe a particular case of the proof (and in fact I think the proof is essentially equivalent to this claim) is:

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group.  Let $C,D$ be cosets (*not assumed* open, closed etc.) each of which has empty interior.  Then $C\cup D$ also has empty interior.

This is not try in general topology, of course: let $C,D$ be the rational, respectively, irrationals, in $\mathbb R$.  However, I cannot decide if being a coset rules out this sort of example.  Is the claim true, and if so, what is a proof?

Comment: @NateEldredge I **think** Matt means Lemma 1.3(ii), which -- FWIW -- the preceding text claims is following/adapting a similar argument given in Rudin's book *Fourier Analysis on Groups*

Comment: For a coset (=right coset, =left coset) in a topological group, having empty interior is equivalent to being non-open.

Comment: BTW, Matt, in that bit of the proof, are they not taking cosets whose closures have empty interior? (Not a rhetorical question, I find that bit of the paper a bit hard to follow.)

Comment: Corrected.  Yes, sorry, that was a typo.  I must admit to not having checked Rudin's book; I'll do this tomorrow when I'm in the office...  (But my question still stands, I think, unless I am very much mistaken.  I am trying to understand how to get the displayed equation at the top of page 10).

Comment: This is false. Take $G=(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^\mathbf{N}$ and let $H$ be a dense subgroup of index 2 (there are many, since $G$ has only countably many closed subgroups of index 2 but has $2^c$ subgroups of index 2). Then $G=H\cup (G-H)$ and both $H,G-H$ have empty interior.

Comment: @YemonChoi: I don't think so.  As I said, top of page 10. I think you could have $K_i = G$ already, and $N_{1,1}$ and $N_{1,2}$ my $C,D$.  The proof then claims that the closure of $G \setminus (C\cup D)$ is all of $G$, which is equivalent to my question.

Comment: @YCor: Great!  That would do it.  Okay, I guess I need to go back to Rudin and try to reconstruct the non-abelian version of his proof...

Comment: Matt: a word of warning, if you read M &N's comments about Lemma 1.3(i) they are suggesting that the original arguments in Rudin may be incomplete, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232351/a-possible-mistake-in-walter-rudin-fourier-analysis-on-groups

Comment: @YemonChoi: Indeed, I think Rudin is also wrong on page 86, for the same reason Ilie and Spronk appear to be wrong.

Comment: @YCor Since the question is aimed at clarifying/correcting a gap in an argument in research-level harmonic analysis (and may even be detecting errors in a standard reference, namely Rudin's book) maybe you can post your comment as an answer. As I am somewhat familiar with the Ilie-Spronk paper and the literature that cites it, I should point out that Matt's question seems to be the result of digging rather deeper into the proofs than most people have done during the last 15 years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Take the (compact abelian) group $G=(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^\mathbf{N}$ and let $H$ be a dense subgroup of index 2 (there are many, since $G$ has only countably many closed subgroups of index 2 but has $2^c$ subgroups of index $2$, and clearly a subgroup of index 2 is either closed or dense). Then $G=H\cup (G\smallsetminus H)$ and both $H$ and its coset $G\smallsetminus H$ have empty interior.

Answer (score 0):

With an additional assumption that there exists an interior point $x\in C\cup D$ such that $x\in C\cap D$, one can prove this fact for any topological group. It doesn't require local compactness.

Note that $e$ is in the interior of $x^{-1}C\cup x^{-1}D$ and both sets are subgroups. Thus, WLOG, $x=e$ and $C$, $D$ are subgroups.

Now pick an open neighbhourhood of $e$ such that $U\subseteq C\cup D$. Pick another open neighbhourhood of $e$ such that $V^2\subseteq U$.
Now an easy algebraic argument shows that $V$ must by a subset of $C$ or $D$. Otherwise, pick $y\in V\setminus D$ and $z\in V\setminus C$. The product $yz$ must be in $U$, so in $C$ or $D$. Both lead to a contradiction.

Comment: A basis of compact open subgroups??  I must be misunderstanding, because that doesn't seem to be true at all for say, $\mathbb{R}$, not even if you meant "relatively compact".

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is for totally disconnected only...

Comment: I will fix it now...

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for the earlier misunderstanding.

Comment: So, why are $x^{-1} C$ and $x^{-1} D$ both subgroups?  This would hold if $x \in C \cap D$ but I don't see why that would have to be true.

Comment: Because they are cosets containing $e$

Comment: Setting aside the WLOG for a moment, since I think it's causing confusion: you seem to be claiming that  the original cosets $C,D$ must have nonempty intersection.  I don't see how that follows from the assumptions.

Comment: @NateEldredge seems to have identified a gap in the argument near the start. You start with x that lies in the union of $C \cup D$, and then you claim that $x^{-1}C$ and $x^{-1}D$ are subgroups. This only works if $x$ belongs to $C$ and $x$ belongs to $D$

Comment: The edited version doesn't address the original question, and the extra assumption seems much stronger than the setting in which @MatthewDaws originally asked his question.